# Determine the closest point in a subspace to a given point

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Let $S$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ given by the intersection of the planes

$$P_1 = \{(x,y,z,w)| x + 3y -2z + w =0\}$$

$$P_2 = \{(x,y,z,w)| 2x - 2y + z - w =0\}$$

$i)$ Find an orthogonal basis of $S$ and $ii)$ determine the Point in $S$ which is closest to the point $P (1,2,2,1)$ with respect to the standard norm given by the dot product.

For the first part of the question, I found a basis and then made it orthogonal with the standard Gram-Schmidt Process,

resulting in a basis of $\left[\begin{array}{c}
-\frac{5}{3} \\
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right]$ , $\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{9}{34} \\
\frac{15}{34} \\
1 \\
0
\end{array}\right]$, $\left[\begin{array}{c}
-\frac{6}{43} \\
-\frac{10}{43} \\
\frac{6}{43} \\
1
\end{array}\right]$.

However, I am unsure how to proceed with the second part of the question, I just cant intuitively understand what it is asking for, is it perhaps the orthogonal Projection of P onto S?

Comment: Yes, the point of $S$ closest to $P$ is the orthogonal projection of $P$ onto $S$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, *none* of those three vectors belongs to $S$. Besides, since $\dim S=2$, $S$ cannot possibly have a basis consisting of $3$ vectors.

A basis of $S$ is $\{v_1,v_2\}$, with $v_1=(1,0,3,5)$ and $v_2=(0,1,1,-1)\}$. It is not orthogonal, but you can get an orthogonal basis form it: $\{v_1,v_3\}$, where$$v_3=v_2-\frac1{\|v_1\|^2}\langle v_2,v_1\rangle v_1=\left(\frac2{35},1,\frac{41}{35},-\frac57\right).$$Now, the point of $S$ closest to $(1,2,2,1)$ is$$\frac1{\|v_1\|^2}\langle(1,2,2,1),v_1\rangle v_1+\frac1{\|v_3\|^2}\langle(1,2,2,1),v_3\rangle v_3=\left(\frac{42}{101},\frac{129}{101},\frac{255}{101},\frac{81}{101}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you, may I ask, how you determined the basis you worked with? It is my understanding that you may find a basis by getting the nullspace of the matrix representing the equations. However, the basis this produces isnt as nice to work with for orthogonalization by hand.

Comment: I solved the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+3y−2z+w=0\\2x−2y+z−w=0\end{array}\right.$$and I got$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}z=3x+y\\w=5x-y.\end{array}\right.$$Then, in order to get $v_1$ I took $x=1$ and $y=0$ and, in order to get $v_2$, I took $x=0$ and $y=1$.